# Configuracion de seguridad para app con keycloack

Tags: login, security, keycloak

Tengo una Aplicación móvil y quiero que actué de la siguiente manera:

Opción 1.1 el cliente se registra verificando su mail con un
código que se envía a su mail

Opción 1.2 - el cliente inicia sesión verificando su mail con un código que se envía a su mail

2 - el usuario mantendrá su sesión abierta siempre hasta que el mismo elija cerrar sesión

3 - la idea es que sea un token + token de refresco
la configuración debe ser con keycloack.

Mi preguntas son:

- La configuración debe ser con oauth2 ?
- Como puedo mantener la sesión siempre abierta ?
- Que tipo de configuracion me recomiendan para este caso?

Comment: Buenas! Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: @AndresGardiol gracias por tu ayuda ! que podria mejorar en este caso ? no me estaria dando cuenta